# tkinter wait_variable doesn't return

Tags: python, tkinter, pause

i've a tkinter toplevel widget were you can type some text, and then press ok. it is created in a function: if you call that funtion the program should wait for a click on the button and than the function should return that text, so that my function have the same use a the *`input`* function in python 3. now my problem is: how can i pause my script **until** the user clicked on a button, so that all other files in my project pause (there happens nothing if the user clicks on a button in another tkinter window) are paused? i tried to use *`button.wait_variable(chosen)`* and when the user clicks on the button the variable "chosen" will change.

```py
def choosefile():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("275x50")
    chosen = tk.BooleanVar()
    chosen.set(False)
    label = tk.Label(root, text="enter name of file (without extention)")
    label.pack(fill="both")
    entry = tk.Entry(root)
    entry.pack(side="left", expand=True, fill="x")
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Ok", command=lambda: [chosen.set(True), output(chosen.get())])
    button.pack(side="right")
    output("waiting")
    button.wait_variable(chosen)
    output("not waiting")
    result = entry.get() + ".py"
    root.quit()
    return result
```

this works ok if you only run this file, but when i this run with main.py(below) the window don't destroy and also not return.

main.py

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Entry, StringVar
import tkinter.font as tkfont
from customtext import CustomText
from execute import Execute
from coloring import color
from files import create, openfile, choosefile
from alert import alert
import keyboard


class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()

        self.width = self.winfo_screenwidth() - 1
        self.height = self.winfo_screenheight() - 1
        self.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

        self.state = StringVar()
        self.state.set("saved")

        self.input = CustomText(self)
        self.input.place(x=10, y=10, width=self.width - 20, height=self.height - 20)
        self.input.bind("<<TextModified>>", lambda a: [color(self.input), self.state.set("unsaved")])

        self.run = Button(self, text="run", command=lambda: [create(self.name.get("1.0", "end-1c"), ".py", self.input.get("1.0", "end-1c")), Execute(self.name.get("1.0", "end-1c")), self.state.set("saved")])
        self.run.place(x=self.width - 70, y=20, width=50, height=30)

        self.exit = Button(self, text="exit", command=lambda: self.destroy())
        self.exit.place(x=self.width - 130, y=20, width=50, height=30)

        self.save = Button(self, text="save", command=lambda: [create(self.name.get("1.0", "end-1c"), ".py", self.input.get("1.0", "end-1c")), self.state.set("saved")])
        self.save.place(x=self.width - 190, y=20, width=50, height=30)

        self.open = Button(self, text="open", command=lambda: self.openfile())
        self.open.place(x=self.width - 250, y=20, width=50, height=30)

        self.name = CustomText(self, border=3, font=('Arial', 13))
        self.name.place(x=self.width - 360, y=21, width=100, height=30)

    def openfile(self):
        if self.state.get() == "unsaved":
            choise = alert("your code is unsaved, save now?")
            if choise == "Ok":
                create(self.name.get("1.0", "end-1c"), ".py", self.input.get("1.0", "end-1c"))
                self.state.set("saved")
        self.input.delete("1.0", "end")
        self.input.insert("end-1c", openfile(choosefile())) # here choosefile is called. 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    keyboard.add_hotkey("ctrl+enter", lambda: [keyboard.write("\b"), Execute(app.input.get("1.0", "end"))])
    app.mainloop()
```

can someone help? thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
i tried to implemant what acw1668  commented and it ***works!*** what i've done: in all my functions, i added a parameter master, so that i at any place in my project can use `tk.Toplevel(master)`. now, since i only one instance of `tk.Tk()` have, it is working correctly.

Comment: It is most likely caused by multiple instances of `Tk()`.

Comment: Try changing `chosen = tk.BooleanVar()` to `chosen = tk.BooleanVar(root)`. Also I think you are misunderstanding what `root.quit()` does. It doesn't destroy the window, it just exits the `.mainloop()`

Comment: @TheLizzard you're right, i will replace it with `root.destroy`

Comment: @acw1668 you're also right, in my question i said it works correctly when i only run `choosefile()`

Comment: @JasperBart It's because when you call `tk.BooleanVar()`, it creates a `tkinter` variable that is attached to the first window not the `root` inside `choosefile()`. That is probably the problem. So you should change `tk.BooleanVar()` to `tk.BooleanVar(master=root)`

Comment: @TheLizzard sorry, check my edit